# Add indication that migration is not an option in the Close dialog

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, moderator-tools, migration

I just encountered a software development question on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (in the Close Votes review queue, but that doesn't matter) which I wanted to migrate to Stack Overflow. The proper way to do that is to close the question as off-topic. However, the specific option ("This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network") was not available:

[image: enter code here]

It took me a while to realize that this question *had already been migrated*, so all I could do is close it with one of the canned off-topic reasons on our site. I'd like some visual indication *in the close dialog* that migration isn't an option in these circumstances; while there is a banner indicating that this question has been migrated, it's not visible without scrolling since this is a rather long question. Even a solution where the option *is* shown but grayed out (and upon hovering shows the reason why it isn't available) would work for me, but I like Monica's suggesting of mimicking the "too old to migrate" message:

[image]

The problem is not only limited to ♦ moderators; Stack Overflow 3k+ users will experience the same issue with migrated questions ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56117913/4751173) - it's the last question migrated to SO while I write this, not particularly close-worthy) – they can't vote to migrate it either.

Comment: I've seen cases where a question was migrated to another site after it was already migrated from its first site...is that staff-only?

Comment: Also, can't you clear the migration history then re-migrate it?

Comment: I guess so: [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1050809/migrated-thru) returns surprisingly few results. I have never used the "clear migration history" option before, will look at it tomorrow since it's marked with a **Warning!** sign :)

Comment: Clearing the migration history is a very useful tool. One example of when it comes in handy is if a post that was originally migrated from another site needs to be closed without locking and deleting it as a rejected migration. Also, there was indeed [one recent case](https://parenting.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/1337/revisions) where a post was migrated from another site then re-migrated by a staff member (with its first migration history still in place); it seems like that's a staff-only feature, can you please check?

Comment: The first panel, the one where you select off-topic, says "too old to migrate" if it is.  Your case is different, but that's where I'd expect to see a "can't migrate" notice.  Oh, except that doesn't seem to be working here on MSE!  I just started to close an MSE question from 2017 and there was no "too old to migrate" there, just the absence of the migrate option on the second panel.  Odd.